# Inexistent manager directory in webapps

Tags: tomcat, openbsd

When I list the applications deployed to my tomcat at localhost:8080/manager/html/list, I can see that both "manager" and "host-manager" are deployed.

Why are their directories not present in /var/tomcat/webapps like the other applications?

I use Tomcat 7.0.35 on OpenBSD.

Comment: With "pkg_info -L tomcat", I have found them in /usr/local/tomcat/webapps.